# How to get related variables according to a condition in R

Tags: r, function, plyr

Hi to all the community members, 
I check all the related questions, but I was unable to find a solution for this.
I have the following DB

```
DB<-data.frame(ID=rep((1:10),10),DISTANCE=1:100,TIME=rep(1:20))
```

and I want to get the maximum value for the column DISTANCE for each ID with the related TIME,i.e:

```
result<-data.frame(ID=1:10,DISTANCE=91:100,TIME=11:20)
```

I already know that

```
aggregate(DB$DISTANCE,by=list(DB$ID),max)
```

could do part of the work, so how can I get the related value for the column TIME according to the maximum value of DISTANCE for each ID?

Many thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: +1 for giving us the data, and showing the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `merge` to get the `TIME` column back:

```
DB.a <- aggregate(data = DB, DISTANCE ~ ID, max)
merge(DB.a, DB)
#    ID DISTANCE TIME
# 1   1       91   11
# 2  10      100   20
# 3   2       92   12
# 4   3       93   13
# 5   4       94   14
# 6   5       95   15
# 7   6       96   16
# 8   7       97   17
# 9   8       98   18
# 10  9       99   19
```

Comment: Thank you @Arun, I really appreciate..easy and without the need to add extra-packages!

Answer (score 3):

I'd do this using `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(DB, .(ID), summarise, mx = max(DISTANCE), TIME = TIME[which.max(DISTANCE)])
```

`ddply` cuts up the `data.frame` according to the levels in `ID`. Then for each subset, it calculates `max(DISTANCE)`, and finds the associated `TIME` using `which.max`.